# JavaFX 8 - How to set NearClip and FarClip on a Parallel Camera?

Tags: 3d, camera, javafx-8, clipping, javafx-3d

I am part of a team building an application that manipulates a visual model using JavaFX 8 3D. We use both a Perspective Camera and a Parallel Camera. The Perspective Camera is working as expected. It is currently working with `isEyeAtCameraZero` false. This was done for maximum compatibility with the Parallel Camera.

The Perspective Camera behaves correctly when `camera.setNearClip()` and `camera.setFarClip()` are called.

The Parallel Camera does not appear to respond to `camera.setNearClip()` and `camera.setFarClip()`. The Parallel Camera does perform near and far clipping, but I have been unable to change the Parallel Camera clipping range.

I am using an algorithm based on the pseudo code on the JavaFX 8 `Camera` javadocs page to calculate the values passed into `camera.setNearClip()` and `camera.setFarClip()`. This appears to work correctly with the Perspective Camera but not the Parallel Camera.

Can anyone offer advice on how to manage the clipping range of the Parallel Camera?

Comment: I am a little late!; but I would like to thank InteractiveMesh. As a result we simulated a ParallelCamera by setting Persective field of view to a very small angle and calculating the camera to target distance required to fill the view with the target object. It is a bit of a kludge, but the end users are happy and it does produce a respectable orthographic view of the scene.

Comment: yours should be the correct answer as it seems possible to simulate a ParallelCamera.   i have just tried values of `camera.setFieldOfView(1);camera.setTranslateZ(-26*cameraDistance);` with cameraDistance being the distance i used for a "normal" perspectiveCamera.  and it looks pretty ok having lost its z depth

Answer (score 2):

The ParallelCamera seems to ignore the clipping distances when calculating the orthogonal projection. Instead the Scene/SubScene's width or height determines the far and near clipping planes according to the package private method:

```
void computeProjectionTransform(GeneralTransform3D proj) {
    final double viewWidth = getViewWidth();
    final double viewHeight = getViewHeight();
    final double halfDepth = (viewWidth > viewHeight) ? viewWidth / 2.0 : viewHeight / 2.0;

    proj.ortho(0.0, viewWidth, viewHeight, 0.0, -halfDepth, halfDepth);
}
```

This makes the ParallelCamera quite useless for 3D rendering in JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

As InnteractiveMesh says, this isn't supported out of the box, but it is possible to override it:

```java
package javafx.scene

import com.sun.javafx.geom.transform.GeneralTransform3D

public class BetterOrthoCamera extends ParallelCamera
{
    public double orthoDepth = 1000.0;

    @Override
    void computeProjectionTransform(GeneralTransform3D var1) {
        double var2 = this.getViewWidth();
        double var4 = this.getViewHeight();
        double var6 = orthoDepth;
        var1.ortho(0.0, var2, var4, 0.0, -var6, var6);
    }

}
```

Note that you may encounter module issues because the method is package private, so we must define our subclass in `javafx.scene`, but running in UNNAMED seems to work for me.

It's also possible to adjust it to be non-symmetric, just change `-var6` and `var6`.