# ParallelCamera NearClip and FarClip

Tags: javafx

According to a previous answered question the scene width or height determines the far and near clipping planes.  So if I set my scene window small enough all the graphics in the group are displayed but if I increase the size of the scene the graphics in the group are clipped in both the near and far.

Is there any other solution with the ParallelCamera that will modify the near and far clip?

Or is it possible something other then the ParallelCamera is the issue?

The only calls I'm using in ParallelCamera is this:

```
                camera.setTranslateX(-scene.getWidth() / 2);
                camera.setTranslateY(-scene.getHeight() / 2);
```

whenever the scene size is changed.

Here is the link to the previously answered question:

[JavaFX 8 - How to set NearClip and FarClip on a Parallel Camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812656/javafx-8-how-to-set-nearclip-and-farclip-on-a-parallel-camera)

Comment: Why wouldn't you link that question?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the far and near clipping plane manually. You are not bound to the default.

Comment: according to the other post and my testing setting near and far clipping plane do nothing

Comment: You are right. I missed the word "parallel". Did you try the solution provided in one of the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812656/javafx-8-how-to-set-nearclip-and-farclip-on-a-parallel-camera

Comment: not really a solution says the parallel camera is useless

Comment: I meant the first comment (not answer) unter the original qustion there, where it is proposed to simulate a parallel camera via a perspective one.